# Using match() for regex on react app getting error

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, match

```
componentDidMount(){
  axios.get('/sites/multiscreen/templates').then(res => {
    if(res.data.template_id.match(/^[a-z0-9]+$/i)){
      this.setState({
        templates: res.data,
      });
    }
  })
}
```

The error I'm getting is this:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like `template_id` isn't a string.

Comment: It's JSON... how would I use match() with json? Convert it to a string?

Comment: Can you post up your `res.data`? Error is saying that `res.data.template_id` is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure about `res.data` that it has value before calling `match`. I suggest you use this:

```
componentDidMount(){
  axios.get('/sites/multiscreen/templates').then(res => {
    if(!!res && 
       !!res.data &&
       !!res.data.template_id &&
       /^[a-z0-9]+$/i.test(res.data.template_id)) 
    {
      this.setState({templates: res.data});
    }
  })
}
```